# С помощью какого компонента Bootstrapv4 можно реализовать данную задачу (см. скрин)?

Tags: bootstrap

С помощью какого компонента Bootstrapv4 можно реализовать данный слайдер (см. скрин)?
[image: Что должно получится)?]

Comment: Здесь не принято задавать вопросы обусловленные [ленью](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5043/%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Answer (score 1):

Примените основы бутстрапа - [сетка](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)(первый пункт документации), это стандартная сетка:

```css
.block {
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class=container>
  <div class=row>
    <div class=col-4>
      <div class=block></div>
    </div>
    <div class=col-4>
      <div class=block></div>
    </div>
    <div class=col-4>
      <div class=block></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Там 5 одинаковых колонок. Три ярких и две более блеклых. Сетка из 12-ти на 5 ровно не делится.

Comment: Уточните свой вопрос, добавьте пример вашего кода, ваши попытки -[mcve] - из того что вы дали, понятно только то, что вопрос по сетке. Делать все с нуля вам тут вряд ли будут. А вот помочь что-то решить, что вы пробовали, и не получается, тогда возможно вы найдете то что ищете.

Comment: там получается slider как такой слайдер изготовить средствами bootstrap?

Comment: дополните свой вопрос, опишите полностью задачу, добавьте пример кода, по каждому новому комментанию, бегать и следить, что же там нового никто не будет